# Redis high RSS memory usage

Tags: memory, redis

When running redis `INFO` command, I'm getting the following:

```
used_memory_rss_human:2.69G
```

I understand this is the amount of memory redis freed but was not released back to the OS

How can I release this memory back to the OS?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Redis Docs](https://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization#memory-allocation):

> Redis will not always free up (return) memory to the OS when keys are
>   removed. This is not something special about Redis, but it is how most
>   malloc() implementations work. For example, if you fill an instance
>   with 5GB worth of data, and then remove the equivalent of 2GB of data,
>   the Resident Set Size (also known as the RSS, which is the number of
>   memory pages consumed by the process) will probably still be around
>   5GB, even if Redis will claim that the user memory is around 3GB. This
>   happens because the underlying allocator can't easily release the
>   memory. For example often most of the removed keys were allocated in
>   the same pages as the other keys that still exist. The previous point
>   means that you need to provision memory based on your peak memory
>   usage. If your workload from time to time requires 10GB, even if most
>   of the times 5GB could do, you need to provision for 10GB.